# how to write this complex query

Tags: mysql

```
 Master Table
nID  Elementtype elementval 
1    volume         5          
1    rating         +          
1    volume         3          
1    rating         -          
2    volume         2          
2    rating         *            
2    volume         4         
2    rating         +          
3    volume         3          
3    rating         +
```

---

```
client      table
  nID       client   
   1        halkins    
   2        narnia
   3        avatar
   4        narnia   
   5        newsco
   6        halkins
```

How do I get the average of volume and sum of rating of three types clientwise,For example for halkins

```
client     No(sum)       volumeavg      ngve   potve    neutral
 halkins    4                 4          1       1         0
```

how to get the other values basically volumeavg in the same query 
or is their any other approach Volume is average of volumes, for halkins 5+3/2=4

Comment: Initial query select c.client,sum(elementval='*') AS ratingneutral,
sum(elementval='-') AS ratingnegetive,sum(elementval='+') AS ratingpositiveve  
FROM client c ,master m
where c.NId = m.NId
GROUP by c.client   how to add the volume part

Comment: @casperOne: How can it be that a question which already has an accepted answer "*cannot be reasonably answered in its current form*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) the tables, then *group* the results:

```
SELECT   client,
         COUNT(*) AS `No(sum)`,
         AVG(IF(Elementtype='volume', elementval, NULL)) AS volumeavg,
         SUM(Elementtype='rating' AND elementval='-') AS ngve,
         SUM(Elementtype='rating' AND elementval='+') AS potve,
         SUM(Elementtype='rating' AND elementval='*') AS neutral
FROM     Master JOIN client USING (nID)
GROUP BY nID
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3075/1/0).